# Opening the corresponding Conversation in a Modal Box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dialog, razor

I am using @Darin Dimitrov's method explained in [Loading a partial view in jquery.dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802378/loading-a-partial-view-in-jquery-dialog) to allow users to click on one of their Private Messages and view it inside a modal box. I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and Razor as my view engine. But I'm having some trouble getting this to work... Below is what I've attempted so far:

The messages are displayed in a table:

```
<tr id="@item.Id" class="openConversationLink">
    <td class="newMessageStatus">@MessageStatus(item)</td>
    <td class="msgSenderName">@item.Sender</td>
    <td class="msgSubject">@item.Subject</td>
    <td class="msgLastUpdated">@item.LastUpdated</td>
    <td class="modalItemActions"></td>
</tr>
```

And inside the same partial view, I got the following script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#conversationModal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 850,
            height: 600,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                var convId = ui.attr('id');
                alert(convId);
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("Conversation", "Message", new { conversationId = convId})');

            }
        });

        $(".openConversationLink").click(function () {
            $("#conversationModal").dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically, I'm not sure what the `event` and `ui` parameters inside the `open` handler refer to. So a little explanation on both would be appreciated. But anyway, even the messages do not get displayed now, I keep getting those error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The
>   name "convId" does not exist in the
>   current context. Source:
>   $(this).load('@Url.Action("Conversation",
>   "Message", new { conversationId =
>   convId})');

Basically, I do not want that line to get triggered until I actually click on one of the rows (to open the conversation dialog), but it seems like it's actually getting triggered when the Messages page opens.

**UPDATE:**

Here's my jQuery code now:

```
$(function () {
    $("#conversationModal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 850,
        height: 600,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var convId = event.target.attr('id');
            alert(convId);
            $(this).load('Message/Conversation/' + convId);

        }
    });

    $(".openConversationLink").click(function () {
        $("#conversationModal").dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Anything that can be done about that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you go any further, you need to understand the key thing here >

Url.Action() method is working on the server side. Whatever is passed on to it has to be decided on the server side. Any variables declared in Javascript at the client-side are totally oblivious to the server-side code hence the compiler is trying to find the convId at the server-side code and obviously can't find it. So it gives the error.

Now saying that, we need to find a way to pass the convId to the server. For that you would need to do some manual string concatenation at the client-side. you can do something like this >

`'@Url.Action("Conversation", "Message")' + '?conversationId='+convId`

You see we used the server side code to generate `/Message/Conversation` and then concatenated it at client side to make it `/Message/Conversation/?conversationId=valueOfconvId`

I hope it makes sense :)

**EDIT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickedId;
   $(function () {
        $("#conversationModal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 850,
            height: 600,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {

                $(this).load('Message/Conversation/' + clickedId);

            }
        });

        $(".openConversationLink").click(function () {
            clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#conversationModal").dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

makes sense now? we are saving the id of the clicked `tr` in a global variable

Comment: Yup totally makes sense. I already figured that out myself (but forgot to update the code here - sorry about that). But I still need to figure out a way to get the value of the `id` of the row (tr) being clicked... Any suggestions?

Comment: Answer accepted :) Thanks for the help man. Now I need to get my automapper configuration right. I hate bugs... :/

Comment: Is there a way to pass the clickedId inside some custom option object to the dialog box? I keep having this requirement over and over again, and I keep trying to find my way around it "hackishly" :)