# About the partial View and Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I read this link [Loading a partial view in jquery.dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802378/loading-a-partial-view-in-jquery-dialog), but since I am still new, I dont know where should I put the codes. Should I put it in my partial view or to the page where the link to create is?..

I'm really new to it and really need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the script that will load the dialog on a view where you will call the partial view.

**fullview.cshtml** (example view)

```
<h1>Some markup goes here</h1>
<div id="dialog" title="Create Album" style="overflow: hidden;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it but it just move to another page, no dialog box is popping, does it have to do with my actionlink? because I just want click the create album link then the dialog box will pop up..

Comment: Actionlink? Unless you did not target your action link and cancel the click event on it (ie. `e.preventDefault`) then it will definitely go to another page.

Comment: I didn't use prevent default and as for the actionlink, it goes like this @Html.ActionLink("Create new","CreateAlbumPartial"); Is there still something lacking on the script or something i should edit?.

Comment: got it, there were minor configuration but still I got it.. Thanks for the help, well appreciated.